# Facebook oAuth Connect results in 502 Bad Gateway when redirecting back to my application

Tags: php, facebook, apache, codeigniter, oauth

I'm working on a mobile web app which requires Facebook connect for authentication. On desktop web everything is working fine, but, when I do exactly the same thing on my iPhone the page results in a 502 Bad Gateway.

It happens on the moment Facebook redirects back to my callback url. What makes is more peculiar is that it doesn't ALLWAYS happen, sometime everything works like a charm.

I'm hoping someone recognizes this problem or these symptoms, what could cause these errors?

My web server is Apache and I'm using PHP as scripting language, nothing special.

-- Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Apparently the problem only occurs when I try to connect through my 3G network, when I'm on Wi-Fi everything works fine..

Comment: Is it SSL? 3G sucks when working with SSL, it breaks the connection to many times.

Comment: Hmm, on my side I don't use SSL. I also tried to trim https to http in the Facebook access request. No changes in the behavior.

Comment: What's the App URI and return address? Can you provide a return address from Facebook before it tries to return?

Comment: The App URI is /login/callback as return address and /login/facebook as access URI. I'm not sure what you mean with return address from Facebook?